# What does longterm mean on kernel.org?

Tags: linux, kernel, version

It's fairly easy to understand EOL, mainline and stable kernel, but I'm not sure about `longterm` here,

[image]

What does it mean, or how does it differ from stable kernel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check *What does "stable/EOL" and "longterm" mean?* @ https://www.kernel.org/category/faq.html

Answer (score 3):

It means that they'll keep backporting fixes to it for a while, but no new development/enhancement goes into it.